# What software can I use (if any) to embed URL links into a .mp4 file without paying for a subscription?

Tags: tags, ide, mp4, video-embedding, wistia

How would I go about embedding links into an existing .mp4 file without going through Videowise, Smartzer, Wistia and the obvious (YouTube/TikTok)?

The goal is to open a URL from a video through a clickable button.

Any help would be much apprecieated, many thanks in advance!

I tried using various video editors but I don't think they're designed to add URL's or buttons that can be clicked in the video.

Comment: One way to embed URL in MP4 is through adding text metadata. You can try FFmpeg for free. Make sure your app has a way to read MP4 metadata. So read the URL on video loading and then assign it as the button click's destination...